# How do I change the size of plots with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have 5 plots split between two rows as shown.

Incorrect:
[image]

I'm trying to create a figure of combined plots where all the plots are the same size and central within their own half of the row similar to the picture below.

Correct:
[image]

My code so far is,

```
figure1 <- grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, nrow=1, widthDetails(0.5))
figure2 <- grid.arrange(plot3, plot4, plot5, nrow=1)
 
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(figure1, top = 'Treatment 1'),
             arrangeGrob(figure2),
               )
```

I've tried using the widths argument but that just shifts the ratio of the space used on the row for each plot. I'm not sure what else to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with patchwork: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I used blank plots and split them accordinly with the widths argument,

```
blank<-rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="white"))
 figure1 <- grid.arrange(blank, plot1, blank,plot2, blank, nrow=1, widths = c(1/9, 1/3, 1/9, 1/3, 1/9))
```